# How can I dynamically create a delete button for a rails object using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a script to dynamically show an index of items on a page when a "show" button is pressed but when I try to add a new button to delete each object shown it throws an error I cant seem to resolve. Here is the whole script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
      $(".js-view-decks").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $.get("/users/" + id + "/decks.json", function(data) {
          var complete = ""
          data.forEach(function(deck) {

            const markup = `
            <fieldset>
              <legend><h4> ${deck.name}

              <%= button_to "View Details", "/users/${deck.user_id}/decks/${deck.id}/", method: "get", form: { style: "display:inline-block"} %>
              <%= button_to "Edit", "/users/${deck.user_id}/decks/${deck.id}/edit", method: "get", form: { style: "display:inline-block"} %>
              <%= button_to "Delete", "/users/${deck.user_id}/decks/${deck.id}/", type: "POST", data: {"_method":"delete"}, form: { style: "display:inline-block"} %>
              </h4></legend>

              <p>
                <%= "Format: ${deck.format}" %> <br/>
                <%= "Cards: ${deck.deck_cards.length}" %>
              </p>
            </fieldset>
            `
            complete += markup
          });
            $("#user_decks").html(complete)
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The error I am getting is this:

```
bad URI(is not URI?): /users/${deck.user_id}/decks/${deck.id}/
```

The dynamically created "view details" and "edit" buttons work fine, but the delete button seems to be having a problem with the URL for some reason and I can't figure out why, any suggestions?

Edit: There seems to have been an issue trying to use the rails helper to generate the delete button. Manually generating the button with a form seems to have worked as follows:

```
<form method='post' action='/users/${deck.user_id}/decks/${deck.id}' data-remote='true' form={ style="display:inline-block"}>
                 <input name='_method' value='delete' type='hidden' />
                 <input value='Delete' type='submit' />
               </form>
```

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash. Also looks like interpolation is not working right there

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks for the suggestion, however I still get the same error if I remove the trailing slash

Comment: You say that the other two links/buttons work? I find it hard to believe, now that I looked a bit closer at your code.

Comment: Haha, yes if I remove the line for the third button, the other two work as I want them to. if you have a better way to handle the whole set, feel free to steer me in a better direction, I'm here to learn

Comment: weird. Let's look at the generated JS with and without third button (broken and working, according to you)

Comment: Here is the generated HTML for the view details button that is working. Including the broken button throws the previously mentioned rails error that doesn't allow the page to load.

`<form style="display:inline-block" class="button_to" method="get" action="/users/1/decks/1/"><input type="submit" value="View Details"></form>`

Comment: Sorry, I have no other ideas about this. It can't happen... :/

Comment: Thanks for trying, I am currently working on changing how the app works to better suit what I need

Comment: unless... button_to treats get and post differently? What if you remove the third button and change type of second to a post. Let's see if it makes it break the page

Comment: Yes, changing it to post breaks it the same way the third button was breaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, changing it to post breaks it the same way the third button was breaking

Ah, we're onto something. The problem here, then, is that button_to happens on server-side. Loooong before you attempt to interpolate a deck into those paths. And `"/users/${deck.user_id}/decks/${deck.id}/"`, as it is, is not a valid uri. But button_to needs it to be a valid uri when you make a POST button. (don't know why, but it's irrelevant. It is actually a surprise that it didn't fail in the other two cases)

A possible solution would be to not use `button_to` and write out the links/forms directly, without rails helpers. That is, `<form>`, not `<%= form_for %>` and `<a>` instead of `<%= link_to %>`.

Comment: Bingo! I created the button manually instead of trying to use the rails helper and it works.

`<form method='post' action='/users/${deck.user_id}/decks/${deck.id}' data-remote='true' form={ style="display:inline-block"}>
                     <input name='_method' value='delete' type='hidden' />
                     <input value='Delete' type='submit' />
                   </form>`

Answer (score 0):

For a better approach create a new file and just set the response to `$("#user_decks")`

you can get more information from [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, and the link provided didn't provide me with much clarification

Comment: the link states that you can create two erb files. one contains a view and other a js file. you can create this loop in view file and use the js.erb file to set the values in your target view.

Comment: @AustinMelchior: he says that instead of retrieving a json response and generating markup on the client, you could have generated the html on the server.

Comment: Got it, this is ultimately a project for an assignment that requires me to use JSON responses to generate my html dynamically